# Control azure webjobs queue scan frequency

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

Azure webjobs invoked when new messages arrive to input queues (on storage or service bus). Is it possible to control frequency of queues scanning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the MaxPollingInterval setting:

> Gets or sets the longest period of time to wait before checking for a
>   message to arrive when a queue remains empty.

Here's how you can set this up:

```
JobHostConfiguration configuration = new JobHostConfiguration();
configuration.Queues.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
```

Note that this interval is only used to check form messages **when the queue remains empty**.